# Two rcpp functions in the same cpp file

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm guessing this is an easy question, but I'm new to Cpp, and am stuck.

I've created a function in R, using Rcpp and:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
```

I can call the function in R and it works as intended. Let's call it `F1()`.

Next, I want to create another function, `F2()`, in the same file cpp that calls the first function. I use standard function call language (i.e., `F1(arguments)`), and it compiles fine through R when I use `sourceCpp()`. But when I try to call `F2()` in R, I get:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "F2"

Any advice?

Thanks.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector F1(NumericVector x) {
  return x * 2;
}
NumericVector F2(NumericVector x) {
    return x *F1(x);
}
 // even if i put return x*x*x instead of x*F1(X), I got the same error

/*** R
F1(42)
F2(51)
*/
```

Comment: You need an export declaration for each exported function. If you call sourceCpp with verbose =TRUE you can see exactly what code is generated.

Comment: That's a duplicate question too...

Answer (score 2):

For each function you have to provide an exporter comment **// [[Rcpp::export]]**.
This line is important to send the function into **R**. Your code must be written as:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector F1(NumericVector x) {
  return x * 2;
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector F2(NumericVector x) {
    return x *F1(x);
}


/*** R
F1(42)
F2(51)
*/
```

Comment: thank u very much, it 's very helpful